# Accordion inside iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a scenario where my iframe get loaded dynamically by onclick function.

I am trying to use accordion inside the iframe but `accordion()` function is not working.

Below is my jquery code

```
 $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

 });
```

is there any solution?

Iframe code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">    
 <script>
     $(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion();
         });
 </script>
 </head>
<body>

<% ApplicationBean app= (ApplicationBean)request.getAttribute("app");%>
<c:out value="${app.getAppName()}"/>

    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Application</h3>
        <div>
            <p></p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Application Name</td>
                        <td><c:out value="${app.getAppName()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Service URL</td>
                        <td><c:out value="${app.getServiceUrl()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Deploy Time</td>
                        <td><c:out value="${app.getDeployTime()}"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${app.isRunning()==true}">Running</c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>Down</c:otherwise> 
                            </c:choose>
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>WSDL</td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${app.getWsdls() }"></c:out>                  
                    </tr>
                </table>

        </div>
        <h3>Libraries</h3>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <h3>Message Flows</h3>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have added jquery & jquery-ui file in parent.html

Comment: As I say in my answer you must add jquery & jquery-ui in the page that is loaded inside the iframe

Comment: there isn't `</td>` end at the last td of the table, but i don't think that is the problem

Comment: You need also to add jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

**all js's needed for accordion() must be inside the iframe**. That includes jquery and jquery-ui and the **CSS files** (jquery-ui.css)

Answer (score 0):

Your accordion initialization code as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

 });
```

If I suppose that the your parent page is `parent.html` and the page you are using as an iframe is `iframe.html`, then code should on the `iframe.html` page and not on `parent.html` page.

Comment: the js in on the same page as iframe jsp but the thing is I don't see any error on the console & also accordion doesn't work.

Comment: Then please post the whole html code of your parent page as well as iframe page

Comment: posted..any solution?

Comment: It seem that you haven't included all the necessary jquery plugin files for the accordion to work on the iframe page. So include all those and try again ! It should work ! :)